# "eigenspaces of the Beltrami operator are one-dimensional." what does this mean?

Tags: harmonic-functions, spherical-harmonics

While going through the book on ellipsoidal harmonics, I came across this argument,
The spectral form of the ellipsoidal Beltrami operator:
$$Be(ρ)S_m^
n (μ, ν) =
[(h_2^3 + h_2^2)p_m^n− n(n + 1)ρ^2]S_m^n (μ, ν)$$
on any ellipsoidal surface confocal to the defining reference ellipsoid. For any fixed
$\rho$ and any pair of indices $(n,m)$, the quantity
$[(h_2^3 + h_2^2)p_m^n− n(n + 1)ρ^2]$
is an
eigenvalue of the operator $Be(\rho)$ with corresponding eigenvector the surface harmonic
$S_m
^n (μ, ν)$. Hence, in the ellipsoidal case, the eigenspaces of the Beltrami
operator are one-dimensional.

I did not understand how it is one dimensional but in the case of spherical harmonics it is $2n+1$ dimensional and what is the consequence of eigenspace being one-dimensional?

Comment: Use `\rho` for $\rho$

Comment: I am guessing it has something to do with symmetry.